# how can I implement unbounded loops in FPGA?

Tags: vhdl, verilog, fpga

I understand that loops that run for predefined number of iterations are unrolled during HLS. But what about loops without predefined bounds? e.g.,

```
for (i = 0; i < j; i++) { ... }
```

How are such loops implemented in FPGAs?

Comment: VHDL has a loop statement with a for iteration scheme which requires static bounds for synthesis or a while iteration scheme which isn't supported for synthesis. See Std IEEE 1076.6-2004 (RTL Synthesis, withdrawn) 8.8.9 Loop statement.  Loop statements inherently parallelize the sequential statements they contain when synthesized.  The size of the resulting hardware has to be known. Also see IEEE Std 1076-2008 (the LRM) 10.10 Loop statement.

Comment: This is a bounded loop; the bound is determined by the type (or subtype) declaration for j.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure how this is VHDL or Verilog related, since you explicitly state HLS and give a C style question.  But certainly in VHDL, unbound loops are not explicitly supported.  There are cases where you can use unbounded loops, but they must terminate at some point.

As user1155120 pointed out, dynamic loop constraints are not supported.  But to expand on that a bit.

Edit:  Initially I used the term "unbounded" when I should have said "dynamic range" loops.  I've updated the answer with that language.

So, first, some types of loops with pseudo-dynamic ranges are supported.  For example:

```
for i in 0 to 7 loop
  for j in 0 to i loop
    ...
  end loop;
end loop;
```

This really isn't dynamic, since these are easily unrolled.  The synthesizer can determine the bounds on this loop.  Clearly `j` can only go from 0 to 7.  But other kinds of dynamic loops are not supported:

```
signal a : natural;
...
for i in 0 to a loop
...
end loop;
```

In this case, the range of the loop is not known statically.

But there is a way to dynamically "bound" loops based on inputs, but it does require knowledge of the bounds of the input.  One can do something like:

```
signal a : natural range 0 to 7;
...
for i in 0 to 7 loop
  if ( i < a ) then
    ...
  end if;
end loop;
```

Now the loop effectively only operates up to the value of `a`.  (Some caution here.  When doing this, memory--flops or latches depending on the context--may be inferred inside the `if`/`end if` for those cases where the the loop terminates early.  There are ways to avoid it, but that's outside the scope of this answer.)

RTL cannot be synthesized to dynamic structures.  So your design will have to be sized for the largest possible case, and then dynamically choose how many iterations up to the maximum supported will be done.

One final note.  There is support for unbounded loops (while loops), though it does require that the loop be terminated.  Let's take the typical free running counter example:

```
signal ctr : unsigned(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
...
process(clk)
begin
  if ( rising_edge(clk) ) then
    ctr <= ctr + 1;
  end if;
end process;
```

This can also be expressed in another manner:

```
process
begin
  wait until rising_edge(clk);
  ctr <= ctr + 1;
end process;
```

And it is possible to use an unbounded loop, for example:

```
process
begin
  while true loop
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    ctr <= ctr + 1;
  end loop;
end process;
```

All of these are synthesizable.

***WARNING*** Discussion below is **crazy** stuff and should not be used as an example of code.  The examples are for discussion purposes only.

And dynamic ranged loops are synthesizable, though their functionality isn't clear.  For example:

```
signal a   : natural := 33;
signal ctr : natural := 0;
...
process
begin
  for i in 0 to a-1 loop
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    ctr <= ctr + 1;
  end loop;
end process;
```

Or even an unbounded loop:

```
process
  variable i : natural := 0;
begin
  while i < a loop
    wait until rising_edge(clk);
    ctr <= ctr + 1;
  end loop;
end process;
```

These both synthesize.  But the latter is especially problematic as it does not simulate well, especially when `i` >= `a`.

Comment: Unbounded loops (while loops) ARE supported ... for simulation. Synthesis requires bounding as above.  The last example can be improved by removing the fragile magic numbers: `subtype a_type is natural range 0 to 7; signal a : a_type; ... for i in a_type loop ...`

Comment: Thanks. I am new to HLS. Is there something inherent at the circuit level that prevents unbounded loops to be implemented? Like they can't be executed within a single clock cycle and require registers to hold the current value of the loop variable?

Comment: @BrianDrummond I answered the question with respect to the context of the OP, which asked "How are such loops implemented in FPGAs?"  This is a question about synthesis, not simulation.  However, my language was imprecise, so I've updated the answer.  Also, the 'magic numbers' were for example's sake only.

Comment: @JRR What do you mean by "HLS"?  In the digital design community, HLS refers to "High Level Synthesis" which is a bit different mechanism to design hardware than HDL (Hardware Description Language).  I'm not familiar with the constraints on HLS and to what kind of constructs to which they map.  It is possible that unbounded loops could be done in an HLS if they map into some sort of execution engine, rather than simple gates.  If you are looking for an HLS specific answer, I suggest you remove the VHDL and Verilog tags and replace them.

Comment: @JRR Also, with respect to VHDL and Verilog, loops must be bounded because they map to static structures.  The architecture of the implemented logic cannot change itself dynamically to inputs (note: there is a mechanism called partial re-configuration which can sort of do this, but it is not something that just pops out of dynamic code--it must be explicitly implemented).

Comment: The most important thing to realize when writing code in VHDL or Verilog is that you are writing a hardware description, not a piece of executable code. Hardware description languages are just that--a more convenient way of representing registers, memories, and combinatorial logic. You need to design before you code. Before you start writing code, you should have some idea of what the resultant logic should look like--you should be able to break it down to registers, clouds of combinatorial logic, memory, etc. If you can't then you probably are going to produce a horribly inefficient design.